# While extracting a text from image using pytesseract , numbers are printing first and then the strings are printed

Tags: python-tesseract

While extracting a text from image using pytesseract, numbers are printing first and then the strings are printed. Why is this happening?

[This is my input image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1thY9my3frR-KU4LiSzamHv3I6Hq6J__q/view?usp=sharing).

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
from pytesseract import Output
from PIL import Image
imginput = cv2.imread('ss.png')
x,img1 = cv2.threshold(imginput, 180, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
img = Image.fromarray(img1)
d = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, output_type=Output.DICT)
print(d)
```

My output:

> 'text':
>   **'71.\n\n72.\n\n73.\n\n74.\n\n75.\n\n76.\n\n77.\n\n78.\n\n79.\n\n80.**n\nPick
>   out the synonym of the word ‘depositary’ :\n\n(A)  inheritor (B) ward
>   (C) patron (D) trustee\nThe fifth chapter comprises three
>   sections.\n(A) of (B) with (C) no preposition (D) on\n\nAntonym of
>   ‘abortive’ is :\n(A) _ successful (B) reproductive (C) instantaneous
>   (D) fruitful\n\nThe one word for a person who doubts in religious
>   practices :\n(A) _ stoic (B)  sceptic (C)  theist (D) pantheist\n\nThe
>   idiom “bury the hatchet’ means .\n(A) keep enmity (B) open enmity (C)
>   stop enmity (D) have no enmity\n\nVictor seldom visits his uncle, Add
>   proper tag question.\n(A) doesn’t he ? (B) isn’the? (C) ishe? (D) does
>   he ?\n\n‘Khalil Gibran is one of the greatest poets of the world.’
>   Pick out the comparative degree of\nthe sentence.\n\n(A) Khalil Gibran
>   is greater than many other poets of the world.\n(B) Khalil Gibran is
>   greater than any other poet of the world.\n(C) Khalil Gibran is
>   greater than any other poets of the world.\n(D) Khalil Gibran is the
>   greatest poet of the world.\n\nThe passive form of ‘I keep my books
>   here.’ is :\n(A) My books keep here (B) My books are keeping here\n(C)
>   Iam kept the books here (D) My books are kept here\n\nPick out the
>   correctly spelt word.\n\n(A) Constellation (B) Consistancy\n(C)
>   Conspirecy (D) Conservatary\nWe need two more players to the team.
>   Supply suitable phrasal verb.\n(A) make out (B) make up (C) make for
>   (D) make of\n11 052/2019 - M\n\n{P.T.0}'}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running with other segmentation modes:

```
Page segmentation modes:
  0    Orientation and script detection (OSD) only.
  1    Automatic page segmentation with OSD.
  2    Automatic page segmentation, but no OSD, or OCR. (not implemented)
  3    Fully automatic page segmentation, but no OSD. (Default)
  4    Assume a single column of text of variable sizes.
  5    Assume a single uniform block of vertically aligned text.
  6    Assume a single uniform block of text.
  7    Treat the image as a single text line.
  8    Treat the image as a single word.
  9    Treat the image as a single word in a circle.
 10    Treat the image as a single character.
 11    Sparse text. Find as much text as possible in no particular order.
 12    Sparse text with OSD.
 13    Raw line. Treat the image as a single text line,
       bypassing hacks that are Tesseract-specific.
```

Add it like so:

```
# Example of adding any additional options.
custom_oem_psm_config = r'--psm 6'
pytesseract.image_to_string(image, config=custom_oem_psm_config, output_type=Output.DICT)
```

Comment: Thanks, it is correctly printing now , i used  r'--psm 6'